# Array access a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays

I have this array structure:

```
array(4) {
 ["js"]=>
 array(1) {
   [""]=>
   array(28) {
     ["prototype/prototype.js"]=>
     string(22) "prototype/prototype.js"
```

When I use `var_dump($arr['js'][0][0])` or `$arr['js'][""][0]` I get an undefined index error: `Notice: Undefined index: js` Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$arr["js"][""]["prototype/prototype.js"];
```

as `$arr` is multidimensional *associative* array.

Comment: var_dump($items["js"][""]["prototype/prototype.js"]); says: Notice: Undefined index: prototype/prototype.js